# Xamarin Forms C# Live calculating Geo location distance

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, geolocation, gps

I'm building a Taxi app and wanted to calculate the distance while the trip is going and update from the driver app side

I used Geolocator for live updates from https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/GeolocatorPlugin, I'm getting random locations and it's not stable on live updates so i changed getting the location after a minute

```
 private async Task StartTrackingAsync(bool tracking)
        {
            try
            {
                PermissionStatus hasPermission = await CrossPermissions.Current.CheckPermissionStatusAsync(Permission.Location);
                if (hasPermission != PermissionStatus.Denied)
                {
                    // Permission Granted
                    // check for req
                    if (tracking)
                    {
                        // Check is listening...
                        if (CrossGeolocator.Current.IsListening)
                        {
                            // Start

                            CrossGeolocator.Current.PositionChanged += CrossGeolocator_Current_PositionChanged;
                            CrossGeolocator.Current.PositionError += CrossGeolocator_Current_PositionError;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            CrossGeolocator.Current.PositionChanged += CrossGeolocator_Current_PositionChanged;
                            CrossGeolocator.Current.PositionError += CrossGeolocator_Current_PositionError;

                            object aType = "Automotive Navigation";
                            if (await CrossGeolocator.Current.StartListeningAsync(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5), 50,
                                true, new ListenerSettings
                                {
                                    ActivityType = ActivityType.AutomotiveNavigation,
                                    AllowBackgroundUpdates = true,
                                    DeferLocationUpdates = true,
                                    DeferralDistanceMeters = 100,
                                    DeferralTime = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(50),
                                    ListenForSignificantChanges = true,
                                    PauseLocationUpdatesAutomatically = false
                                }))
                            {

                                tracking = true;
                            }
                        }

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        CrossGeolocator.Current.PositionChanged -= CrossGeolocator_Current_PositionChanged;
                        CrossGeolocator.Current.PositionError -= CrossGeolocator_Current_PositionError;

                        await CrossGeolocator.Current.StopListeningAsync();


                        tracking = false;

                    }

                }
                else
                {
                    // Permission Denied
                    await DisplayAlert("Location Error", "Error Getting Location", "OK");
                }

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                // Error Accured
                await DisplayAlert("Location Error", "Error Getting Location: " + ex.Message, "OK");
            }
        }

        private void CrossGeolocator_Current_PositionError(object sender, PositionErrorEventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void CrossGeolocator_Current_PositionChanged(object sender, PositionEventArgs e)
        {
            Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(async () =>
            {

                Plugin.Geolocator.Abstractions.Position position = e.Position;

                if (Cposition != e.Position)
                {
                    Cposition = e.Position;
                    mainmap.MoveToRegion(MapSpan.FromCenterAndRadius(new Xamarin.Forms.Maps.Position(position.Latitude, position.Longitude), Distance.FromMiles(1)).WithZoom(2));

                    loader.IsVisible = false;
                    mainmap.IsVisible = true;
                    local.Lat = position.Latitude;
                    local.Lng = position.Longitude;
                }


            });
        }

        private void DistanceUpdate(bool w = false)
        {
            Device.StartTimer(new TimeSpan(0, 0, 1), () =>
            {
                UpdateDistance();
                return w;
            });
        }

        private async  void UpdateDistance()
        {
            // Get Trip Location
            Models.Location SLocal = Trip.Location;

            Xamarin.Essentials.Location startTrip = new Xamarin.Essentials.Location(SLocal.Lat, SLocal.Lng);

            try
            {
                if (local != null)
                {

                    Xamarin.Essentials.Location OnTrip = new Xamarin.Essentials.Location(local.Lat, local.Lng);

                    double distance = Xamarin.Essentials.Location.CalculateDistance(startTrip, OnTrip, DistanceUnits.Kilometers);
                    double t = tdistance + distance;

                    tdistance = Math.Round(t, 2);

                    if (Trip.Key != null)
                    {
                        _firebaseDatabase.UpdateTripDriverLocation(Trip.Key, local);

                        if (Trip.Status == "Started")
                        {
                            _firebaseDatabase.UpdateTripLocation(Trip.Key, local);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                // Unable to get location

                await DisplayAlert(ex.Source, "ERROR: " + ex.Message, "OK");

            }
        }
```

I'm not getting the current location but a random location and the distance produces more 5000km in 2 minutes before the driver starts moving

Comment: What is your issue?

Comment: I'm having difficulty calculating with that plugin, and i can't get accurate distance when i subtract the geo coordinates